# Unbox numerical value in c++/winrt with conversion

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

Is there a way to unbox numerical value regardless of type? For ex. boxing `int` and then unboxing `double` or `long long` (if the conversion is possible). The point is to be able to unbox from some unknown type to known type if the conversion is possible.

Now it behaves like this:

```cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable boxed_value = winrt::box_value(30);
int i = winrt::unbox_value<int>(boxed_value); //OK
double d = winrt::unbox_value<double>(boxed_value); //Exception
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable boxed_value = winrt::box_value(30);
int i = unbox_value_with_conversion<int>(boxed_value); //OK
double d = unbox_value_with_conversion<double>(boxed_value); //OK
```

Comment: just in case... `auto` is not an "unknown type". The exact type is known at compile time. `auto` only makes the compiler infer the type. Maybe in your real code the situation is different though

Comment: @idclev463035818 `auto` here is actually `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable` but for readability i used `auto` there as its not part of the problem. I edited example to make it more clear. Real clue here is to not throw exception and do correct conversion from `int` to `double`

Comment: [unbox_value_or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/unbox-value-or) shows you how to determine the type stored behind the `IInspectable`. All you need now is a set of typelists that encode convertibility. And a good choice for reporting inability to unbox or unbox and convert.

Comment: @IInspectable May you provide some code how to do it as I do not get it. I know that I could chained `unbox_value_or` one after another like `unbox_value_or<int>(boxed, unbox_value_or<double>(boxed, 0.0));` But that solution is not quit 'automatic' and also not quit efficient and I do knot know how to do it different way.

Comment: I might try to put something together, but that will have to wait some 2 weeks until after my vacation.

Comment: `unbox_value_or` doesn't actually query the boxed type - it merely attempts to query `IReference<T>`, just like `unbox_value`. If you want to runtime query the boxed type, a better bet is to use `IPropertyValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know (or don't care) which type of value has been boxed, `IReference<T>` won't be fun to use. Chaining a bunch of `unbox_value/unbox_value_or` calls will incur a series of `QueryInterface` calls, which is a very inefficient way to do this. Better, would be to use [IPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.IPropertyValue?view=winrt-19041). It already performs scalar conversions, and handles errors like overflow.

```cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable boxed_value = winrt::box_value(30);
int i = boxed_value.as<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IPropertyValue>().GetInt32();
double d = boxed_value.as<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IPropertyValue>().GetDouble();
```

If you prefer, it should be a simple (if slightly repetitive/tedious) exercise to provide the template specializations for your `unbox_value_with_conversion`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
T unbox_value_with_conversion(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value)
{
  return winrt::unbox_value<T>(value);
}

template <>
int32_t unbox_value_with_conversion<int32_t>(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value)
{
  return value.as<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IPropertyValue>().GetInt32();
}

// Rest of specializations...
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement a way to unbox numerical value regardless of type, you could try to wrap the automatic type conversion into the unbox_value_with_conversion method, taking the int, double and long long types you mentioned as examples.

**Function declaration**

```
template<class T>

T unbox_value_with_conversion(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value);
```

**Function definition**

```
template<class T>

inline T MainPage::unbox_value_with_conversion(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value)
{
    T res{};
    auto vv = value.as<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IPropertyValue>();
    if (vv.Type() == winrt::Windows::Foundation::PropertyType::Int32)
    {
        int32_t tt = vv.as<int32_t>();
        res = (T)tt;
        return res;
    }
    if (vv.Type() == winrt::Windows::Foundation::PropertyType::Double)
    {
        double dd = vv.as<double>();
        res = (T)dd;
        return res;
    }
    if (vv.Type() == winrt::Windows::Foundation::PropertyType::Int64)
    {
        long long llong = vv.as<long long>();
        res = (T)llong;
        return res;
    }
    return T();
}
```

**Type conversion**

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable boxed_value1 = winrt::box_value(30);
double dd1 = unbox_value_with_conversion<double>(boxed_value1);
long long llong1= unbox_value_with_conversion<long long>(boxed_value1);
```